# Add a json value to an existing key's value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects and set each object on a new array with the shared parentId as the key. So if two objects had the same parentId they would appear on the new array under the same parentId key.

```
someArry =  [{
        "Id": "111",
        "parentId": "1234",
        "Name": "name1"
    }, {
        "Id": "222",
        "parentId": "1234",
        "Name": "name2"
    }]
let output = [];
let obj = {};
for (let i=0; i<this.someArray.length; i++) {

    let li = this.someArray[i];
    
    if (obj[li.parentId]) {
        obj[li.parentId] //... I need to be able to add another value to the same parentId object
    } else {
        obj[li.parentId] = li; //adds the first occurence 
    }
    output.push(obj);
}
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
[{
    "1234": [{
        "Id": "111",
        "parentId": "1234",
        "Name": "name1"
    }, {
        "Id": "222",
        "parentId": "1234",
        "Name": "name2"
    }]

}]
```

Comment: Fixed my answer - you have to make the first item an array as well. Works (verified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.push()` for this, for example:

```
if (obj[li.parentId]) {
    obj[li.parentId] = obj[li.parentId].push(li);
}
else {
    obj[li.parentId] = [li]; //note adding an array of obj, not obj
}
```

Another way is `Array.concat()` - which in this case will look the same

reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)